# Using malloc in a constructor of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, malloc

Let's say I have a class which will be used to create either tree or list structure. Let's call it

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class Node{
  // some data
  Node<K,V>* next;
  Node() {
    next = static_cast<Node<K,V>*>( malloc( sizeof(Node<K,V>) ));
  }
};
```

By doing this I get a following compiler error:

> there are no arguments to 'malloc' that depend on a template
>   parameter, so a declaration of 'malloc' must be available (if you use
>   '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an
>   undeclared name is deprecated)

Is there any way to use malloc in such a way without having to use deprecated code? I want to use malloc instead of new because I'd like to do some more advanced memory management up there.

Comment: This is an unusual `Node` class. You have what appears to be a linked-list node that allocates the next node automatically, which under normal circumstances would cause infinite recursion, but in fact you are using `malloc` which doesn't call the constructor of the object you're creating which stops the recursion. I'm not sure if this is really smart or really not.

Comment: Are you sure you're not simply missing including cstdlib? (and saying `std::malloc`?)

Comment: It sounds like you're not including stdlib.h which declares the malloc function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler error is telling you that it does not have a declaration of what `malloc` is. You are missing the include that declares that function.

Other than that, the approach is broken. You are writing a generic tree, but because of the use of `malloc` you are limiting the use to POD types (I am assuming that `K` and `V` are stored in the `Node`). You should use `new` instead that will call the constructor for the type, not just allocate memory.

Comment: If he uses `new` then he will cause infinite recursion. I don't know if that is on purpose or not that he used `malloc`. He could be using placement `new` somewhere so it's not limited to POD types.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: True that, but I believe that to be another bug in the implementation... :) There is no sensible way of implementing a list with an extra dangling node at the end, `malloc` does not guarantee that the memory would be initialized, which in turn means that you cannot differentiate the *tail* from any other node in the list, and you have no clue as to where to stop following the chain of nodes.

Comment: That is true, but he could have removed the part that sets it to 0. Oh well, weird question. The world will never know.

Comment: Oh, right that was just the include thing, stupid me. POD types are enough for me because I just want to create a SkipList with a good memory trick for my Algorithms and Data Structure class. No serious engineering up here intended :). Thanks for your help.

And well there's a bug in the constructor, but my point was just to ask about the malloc thing. I just wrote it too fast because I wanted to just show the allocation issue. Sorry guys for my rush.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you are missing `#include <cstdlib>` or `#include <stdlib.h>`. The compiler is complaining about a missing declaration. Those include files provide one.